# Sifr does not display custom/dynamic text

Tags: jquery, plugins, sifr

I am using the sifr plugin from here:http://jquery.thewikies.com/sifr/

and I have generated a swf using http://www.sifrgenerator.com/

I have build set to 436 and version set to 3.

My page only shows the default text that was set inside the swf by the generator. When I try to set the content property to let's say 'hello', it still displays the default text. If you look in the generated html however, you can see that the 'txt' flash var is set to 'hello'. Is there something wrong with the swf that was generated? Maybe the 'dynamic text' option was not set? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery sIFR plugin is based on sIFR 2, and is not compatible with sIFR 3.